# How do you create association in after_build in factory bot rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, associations, factory-bot

I have a data model where `account` has a unique validation on a subdomain.

Most of my other objects are associated with the `account` object.

In my data model, a `product` has an `account_id` and a `program_id`

In FactoryBot I would like to write something like :

```
create(:product, :with_program, account: account)
```

Then to have all associated resources created with this particular account.

and in my `product` factory :

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :product do
    association :account
    association :program
    trait :with_program do
      after_build do |product|
        product.program = create(
          :program,
          :with_author,
          account: product.account
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

However this directly creates the program which in turn recreates an account them  triggers the uniqueness validation on account.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :program do
    association :account
  end
end
```

So far the only solution I found is to create all associations product relies on before creating the actual product and passing them to the `create method` :

```
  let(:program) do
      create(
        :program,
        :with_future_start_date_sessions,
        account: account,
        author: author
      )
    end
create(
        :product,
        :draft,
        program: program,
        account: account
      )
    end
```

Is there a smarter way to pass down the `account` to all `product` associations and create them in a `trait` or something equivalent?

Answer (score 3):

When creating complex associations I always prefer to do it with a top down approach. Instead of creating products with account, try creating an account with products, that way you wouldn't need to create associations before hand.

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :account do
    # account attributes...

    trait :with_products do
      transient do
         product_count {2}
      end

      after(:build, :create) do |account, evaluator|
         create_list(
           :product,
           evaluator.product_count, 
           :with_program, 
           account: account
         )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then you could create products by calling

```
# 1 account, 5 products
FactoryBot::create(:account, :with_products, product_count: 5)
# 5 accounts with 1 product each
FactoryBot::create_list(:account, 5, :with_products, product_count: 1)
```